# Is the following allocation of memory useful?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I found this piece of code in the following link

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm

```
Line::Line(const Line &obj)
{
cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
ptr = new int;
*ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}
```

where Line is defined as:

```
class Line
{
public:
  int getLength( void );
  Line( int len );             // simple constructor
  Line( const Line &obj);  // copy constructor
  ~Line();                     // destructor

private:
  int *ptr;
 };
```

So help me understand.. What is the point in allocating memory for *ptr inside the Copy constructor ? By assigning it to *obj.ptr, essentially they are both pointing to the same locations in memory? Why should I use the new here, if it is only going to perform a shallow copy, that is copy the pointer address of the intended variable ?

Comment: Smells like an infinite recursion (although avoided here)

Comment: This is the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1553090).  It's a shame that the example is so contrived.  It's very unusual to allocate memory for a single `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way for making deep copies. The pointers don't point to the same location, since you dynamically alocated ptr (so it has a it's own new location). After that your copying just the value of the pointer, by dereferencing them.

Comment: Not copying the value of the pointer, copying the value of the object (in this case an `int`) pointed to by the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Line` instance has its own dynamically allocated `int`.  The copy constructor is allocating a new `int` and then copying the `value` of the int being pointed at, it is not copying the pointer itself.